# More efficient way to calculate standard deviation of a large list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am trying to calculate a bunch of standard deviations of a list about 20,000 values long. Here is an example of my code:

```
from statistics import stdev

def main():
    a = [x for x in range(0,20000)]
    b = []

    for x in range(2, len(a) + 2):
        b.append(stdev(a[:x]))

    print(b)

main()
```

This method is extremely slow and I am trying to figure out a way to make it more efficient. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
[Done] exited with code=null in 820.376 seconds
```

Comment: yu can give a try to numpy.

Comment: `stdev` computes the standard deviation. Why are you recomputing the standard deviation 20000 times, and appending it to list?

Comment: What's with the range? `a[:len(a)]` is the same as `a[:len(a)+1]`, so you're just doing the same operation twice at the very end.

Comment: @CoryKramer Apparently, the question has been edited. It asks for an entire list of incrementally constructed tightly related standard deviations, so the question actually makes sense. I retract the close vote.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I need to recompute it because this is calculating standard deviation of a price-earnings ratio. This data looks back 20,000 days and obviously changes overtime. I need to see changes in standard deviation of this list. If that makes sense

Comment: More of a math problem: [incremental-computation-of-standard-deviation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102978/incremental-computation-of-standard-deviation)

Comment: One of the things that kills performance here is constant re-creation of a sublist via `[:x]`, and constant re-iterating over the tail to compute the sum. It should instead be computed from the tail end up, by keeping a tally of the sums so far, and adding one point at a time. (Hint: lists can be easily reversed.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you want an expanding standard deviation, for which I'd use the pandas library and the [pandas.Series.expanding](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.expanding.html) method:

```
In [156]: main()[:5]
Out[156]: 
[0.7071067811865476,
 1.0,
 1.2909944487358056,
 1.5811388300841898,
 1.8708286933869707]

In [157]: pd.Series(range(20000)).expanding().std()[:5]
Out[157]: 
0         NaN
1    0.707107
2    1.000000
3    1.290994
4    1.581139
dtype: float64
```

where you could easily slice away the first element and convert to a list if you wanted:

```
In [158]: pd.Series(range(20000)).expanding().std()[1:6].tolist()
Out[158]: 
[0.7071067811865476,
 1.0,
 1.2909944487358056,
 1.5811388300841898,
 1.8708286933869707]
```

although Series are a much more useful datatype for working with time series than lists, and definitely more performant:

```
In [159]: %timeit pd.Series(range(20000)).expanding().std()
1.07 ms ± 30.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Alright, I'll take a look at Pandas. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

You can keep track of the sum of values and values squared:

```
from math import sqrt

a = range(0,20000)

def sdevs(a):
    sds = [0]
    n = 1
    sum_x = a[0]
    sum_x_squared = a[0]**2

    for x in a[1:]:
        sum_x += x
        sum_x_squared += x**2
        n += 1
        # as noted by @Andrey Tyukin, statistics.stdev returns
        # the unbiased estimator, hence the n/(n-1)
        sd = sqrt(n/(n-1)*(sum_x_squared/n - (sum_x/n)**2))
        sds.append(sd)
    return sds

sds = sdevs(a)
print(sds[10000])
# 2887.184355042123
```

This takes about 24 ms on a 10 years old PC.

Comment: Aaah, no, that's not unbiased estimator (or is it? +1/-1? I don't know). The idea is good, but the details are tricky enough that one might want to use DSM's library-based answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at this on my machine. Thank you for the input!

Comment: @AndreyTyukin You're right, `statistics.stdev` returns the unbiased version, I update the answer.